# Cannot Render REST API Response in react

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am having issue with rendering the REST API response in React. I am able to see the response in console and its working there. But when I am trying to render it in UI, I am getting an error which says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'State' of undefined` .
I have snipped the required code and here it is.

```
  render() {
    const { getdetails } = this.state;
    const itemID = 'ITAINUAT69-8982';

    if (!getdetails ) {
      return <div>Loading Please Wait...</div>;
    }
    else {
      return (
     <div>
               {getdetails.itemID.State} // when trying to render directly, not working
 // also not working in loop.
                  {/* 
                  <ul>  
                   {getdetails.itemID.map((detail, index) => (
                      <li key={detail.index}>
                         {detail.State}
                      </li>
                    ))}
                    </ul> */}
            </div>
          );
        }
      }
    }
    export default Items;
```

Here is the response sample in Postman & console.

```
   {
    "ITAINUAT69-8982": {
        "State": "Not Assigned",
        "SubmitDate": "2020-09-11T04:39:51Z",
}
```

Thanks Everyone.

Comment: Have you tried updaing the initial state of `getdetails` to `undefined` or `null` instead of an empty string?

Comment: Hi @LyndenNoye. Thanks for your reply. As this API call is Asynchronous , In the render method I am checking if the array is empty, donot render it. That's what you are asking ?

Comment: no i mean in your component's constructor, you are setting your initial state to an empty string. in your render function, the only way your code will try an access `getdetails.itemID.State` is if your `if` statement isn't working the way you think it is. a good place to start debugging when you're not sure what's wrong is to validate your assumptions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because in the first render `getdetails` is empty. you can fix this with optional chain operator:

```
Object.keys(getdetails)?.[0]?.State
```

or

```
getdetails?.[itemID]?.State
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The error is gone by getdetails?.itemID?.State but nothing is showing on the screen. I can see in console but not on the screen. Why is that please?

Comment: Thanks alot. Its working for me now. I will accept it as a solution. Many thanks to you and all other friends for helping me out.